# MassTransit endpoint name is ignored in ConsumerDefinition

Tags: masstransit, servicebus

The `EndpointName` property in a `ConsumerDefinition` file seems to be ignored by MassTransit. I know the ConsumerDefinition is being used because the retry logic works. How do I get different commands to go to a different queue? It seems that I can get them all to go through one central queue but I don't think this is best practice for commands.

Here is my app configuration that executes on startup when creating the MassTransit bus.

```
        Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(_config.ServiceBusUri, host => {
                host.SharedAccessSignature(s =>
                {
                    s.KeyName = _config.KeyName;
                    s.SharedAccessKey = _config.SharedAccessKey;
                    s.TokenTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    s.TokenScope = TokenScope.Namespace;
                });
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("publish", ec =>
            {
                // this is done to register all consumers in the assembly and to use their definition files
                ec.ConfigureConsumers(provider);
            });
```

And my handler definition in the consumer (an azure worker service)

```
public class CreateAccessPointCommandHandlerDef : ConsumerDefinition<CreateAccessPointCommandHandler>
{
    public CreateAccessPointCommandHandlerDef()
    {
        EndpointName = "specific";
        ConcurrentMessageLimit = 4;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(
        IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<CreateAccessPointCommandHandler> consumerConfigurator
    )
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Immediate(2);
        });
    }
}
```

In my app that is sending the message I have to configure it to send to the "publish" queue, not "specific".

```
EndpointConvention.Map<CreateAccessPointsCommand>(new Uri($"queue:specific")); // does not work
EndpointConvention.Map<CreateAccessPointsCommand>(new Uri($"queue:publish")); // this does work
```

Comment: Ryan, what is 'provider' in this line 'ec.ConfigureConsumers(provider);'? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are configuring the receive endpoint yourself, and giving it the name `publish`, that's the receive endpoint.

To configure the endpoints using the definitions, use:

```
cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
```

This will use the definitions that were registered in the container to configure the receive endpoints, using the consumer endpoint name defined.

This is also explained in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/#endpoint-configuration).

Comment: Thanks Chris! Does this also eliminate the need to call EndpointConvention.Map<T> in the publisher? ... I guess it wouldn't because the publisher has no way to know the consumers. Nevermind.